# Generating forms to fit in a table

Tags: javascript, html

So I have two forms side by side, and what I'm trying to do is allow the user to generate as many forms as he/she wants, and have each form stored as table data, two per row.  The issue I'm having is that the forms won't store in a table, and I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong.  I start out making a form to find out how many forms the user wants to generate.

```
<table border='1'>
<span id='exForms'>
  <input type='text' name ='number' id='number'>
  <button type='button' onclick="add()">Add</button>
</span>
</table>
```

Next the number is sent to add()

```
add()
{
  var number = document.getElementsByName('number')[0].value;
  var x = document.getElementById('exForms');

  number = parseInt(number);
  var i;
  x.innerHTML="";
  x.innerHTML+="<tr><th>Form1</th> <th>Form2</th></tr>";
  for(i = 0; i<number; i++)
  {
     x.innerHTML+="<tr><td><input type='text' name='commandsc[]'></td><tr><td><input type='text' name='commandsi[]'></td></tr>";
  }
  x.innerHTML+="<input type='submit' name ='submit' value='submit'>";
}
```

The output is basically all the forms on a line then a submit button.
Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve your problem by adding the new created row to the existing table tbody.

See this link how to do it: http://www.roseindia.net/javascript/javascript-add-row-to-table.shtml

Answer (score 0):

This is the real layout:

```
<span id="exForms">
  <input type="text" name="number" id="number">
  <button type="button" onclick="add()">Add</button>
</span>
<table border="1"></table>
```

In short, your layout is invalid. That's why the further changes you did in the layout didn't work as expected.

`exForms` is not inside table. Also, planning something like

```
<table><span><tr/></span></table>
```

was a bad idea.